# Install existing Laravel project in AWS EC2

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I have my Laravel5 project done in the localhost. I made a new Instance and used Ubuntu. Installed Apache2, PHP5.6, MySQL, PHP Mcrypt. Everything seems fine, but **how can I put my project with its database on the server?**

Comment: It's same as you setup the existing project. Just edit your .env file with your the database connection information.

Comment: I don't get it. How it is the same?

Comment: how did you setup your database in your localhost?

Comment: For the code part, just upload the application files to the server and set the document root to the `public` directory. For the database, if you've used migrations to create the database structure, then just run the migrations on the serve. Otherwise create an SQL dump of your database and import it on the server.